# Discord.py 'VoiceState' object has no attribute 'voice_channel'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I use a class structure. I'm writing a Discord bot, for play sound. but I'm faced with a problem.

My `music.py` file:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


class muzikkomut(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command(pass_context=True)
        async def play(self, mesaj):
            kanal = mesaj.message.author.voice.voice_channel
            await self.bot.join_voice_channel(kanal)


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(muzikkomut(bot))
```

Comment: What is your question? What are you trying to achieve? What have you tried? What are the errors?

Comment: my music bot is not connecting to the audio channel but I get this error.

discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'VoiceState' object has no attribute 'voice_channel'

Answer (score 0):

First of all, You must show bot, where he must go.

```
channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
```

Next connect bot to voice channel.